# Excel to CSV to TXT cells with double quotes

Tags: excel, batch-file, csv

I have an Excel spreadsheet with values in each of the cells that I'm looking to convert to a comma-delimited text file. Currently I have a vbs script that is converting the excel file to a csv, then in a batch script I am renaming the `*.csv` to a `*.txt`. This works well for 90% of the cell values until we get to double quotes (`"`)

Some of my cells include values surrounded in double quotes and need to be displayed this way in my txt file. Instead, I get this:

### Double Quotes

```
Excel Cell A1: "Hello"
.csv Cell A1: "Hello"
.txt Cell A1: """Hello"""
```

### Two Double Quotes

```
Excel Cell A1: ""Hello""
.csv Cell A1: ""Hello""
.txt Cell A1: """""Hello"""""
```

### Three Double Quotes

```
Excel Cell A1: """Hello"""
.csv Cell A1: """Hello"""
.txt Cell A1: """""""Hello"""""""
```

It appears that, when you rename a csv to a txt, it duplicates all double quotes, and adds an additional double quote. Does anyone know why this is? Or if there's a work around?

I've tried creating a new `*.csv` file in Excel, saving the value `"Hello"` and renaming it to a `*.txt`, it still shows up as `"""Hello"""` when opened in Wordpad/Textpad/Word. So the issue isn't with my vbs conversion script. I've also tried creating an excel spreadsheet and simply renaming it to `Book1.txt` and the same issue occurs. It seems that whenever a cell is converted to a `*.txt`, extra quotes are added for some reason.

I've seen [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;291296) but it seems odd that additional double quotes are added during a file conversion.

### My vbs script

```vbs
if WScript.Arguments.Count < 2 Then
    WScript.Echo "Error! Please specify the source path and the destination. Usage: XlsToCsv SourcePath.xls(x) Destination.csv"
    Wscript.Quit
End If
Dim oExcel
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Dim oBook
Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(Wscript.Arguments.Item(0))
oBook.SaveAs WScript.Arguments.Item(1), 6
oBook.Close False
oExcel.Quit
WScript.Echo "Done"
```

*Relevant Batch Script Command*

```
Rename SubvarList.csv SubvarList.txt
```

Comment: Are you doing this for 1 excel file? And have you just tried changing the file extension from `.csv` to `.txt`? That shouldn't change anything...

Comment: How can renaming a file change the contents?  What exactly is the VBS script doing?

Comment: a `csv` is simply a plain textfile. Renaming it should not change anything inside it.

Comment: @MarkNash: much more important: what does the batch-script do? For sure not just a `rename`.

Comment: @Mark Nash: I've updated the post with the script information. The script is simply opening the file in excel and saving it as a csv.

Comment: @John Bustos: I've tried both the Batch command "rename" and physically renaming from .csv to .txt. When I view the CSV in excel, the cell is "Hello" but the moment is becomes a .txt it becomes """Hello"""

Comment: @pnuts: I think you're implying that I'm importing a text file into excel? No, I'm starting with an excel file and converting to a txt via a csv file.

Comment: I've viewed it in notepad, text pad, and Word. They all give the same display.

Comment: Windows 7. Not sure what you mean by "type of .csv", I've tried direct to txt from the excel document but it happens the same way. I'm not sure which character set I'm using.

Comment: Am I the only one who this is happening to? Could you create a csv with a cell value of '"Hello"' and then rename it to a .txt?

Comment: the additional `"`s are done by Excel, not by batch. `type test.csv" proves. I am quite annoyed now...

Comment: _It appears that, when you rename a csv to a txt, it duplicates all double quotes, and adds an additional double quote_ No. It only renames the file. All other things you are seeing are artifacts of excel, and whatever set of processes you are following

Answer (score 0):

The workaround seems pretty easy. Once you have the file converted, do a find for double quotes, and replace with single quotes. So...

```
FIND: ""
REPLACE: "
```

Comment: Do you have a way to automate this? The more manual steps I add to the process, the less accessible it is.

Comment: If you want to simplify this, move that batch file rename step into your VBS file.

Answer (score 0):

In the .csv files only if `,` or `.`(Special Characters) are provided in the cells, while converting this file to .txt format, `""` double quotations will be added in the .txt file automatically.

To avoid multiple entries of double quotation in the .txt files, please do not include any quotation marks in the .csv file before conversion.